# New Firebase init failed

Tags: error-handling, firebase, typeerror

Wanted to try out the new firebase. However I can't get it working.

```
app-88ac8456cb.js:14207 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.intializeApp is not a function
```

I was using ES6 imports, however even if I use commonjs like in the docs, its not working.

```
const config = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: ".....firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://.....firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: ".....appspot.com",
};

let firebase = require('firebase');

let fireapp = firebase.intializeApp(config);
```

Installed: "firebase": "^3.0.1"

Node: 6.2.0

And using gulp with browserify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intializeApp` is a typo. You want `initializeApp`.

If you cut and paste that from somewhere let me know and we can try and get it fixed!

Comment: Thanks! 
Yeah the typo is from the npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: ".....firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://.....firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: ".....appspot.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.database().ref(...)
//or
let fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
fb.database().ref(...)
```